# Reversing the sort order of a cte

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

In Microsoft SQL Server, the following works, but produces:

> ,Son,Dad,Granddad,Great Granddad

whereas I need it to say:

> Great Granddad,Granddad,Dad,Son

```
declare @Family Table(
ID Int Identity(100,1) Primary Key
,Person varchar(128)
,ParentID Int default 0

)
insert into @Family(Person,ParentID) values('Great Granddad',0)
insert into @Family(Person,ParentID) values('Granddad',100)
insert into @Family(Person,ParentID) values('Dad',101)
insert into @Family(Person,ParentID) values('Son',102)
DECLARE @ID Int = 103
;with cte1 as (
    select 
         @ID AS cteID
        ,ID
        ,ParentID
        ,Person as ctePerson
    from @Family
    where ID = @ID -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
    UNION ALL
    select @ID, F.ID, F.ParentID, F.Person
    from @Family F
    join cte1 P on P.ParentID = F.ID -- this is the recursion
) 
-- cte2 can reverse the sort order based on something built in (OVER?)
-- ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ? DESC) AS Row

,cte3 AS(
    select ID as cte3ID,(
        SELECT ',' + ctePerson
        FROM cte1
        WHERE cteID = F.ID
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) as People
    from @Family F
    where ID=@ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not order the result of a recursive CTE by using another CTE, as the results of CTEs are semantically tables, and therfore the order is not guaranteed. Instead order when selecting from a CTE, just als like with normal tables.

I would suggest to insert a field representing the level or relationship and order by that:

```
;with cte1 as (
    select 
         @ID AS cteID
        ,ID
        ,ParentID
        ,Person as ctePerson
        ,0 lvl -- starting level with 0
    from @Family
    where ID = @ID -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
    UNION ALL
    select @ID, F.ID, F.ParentID, F.Person
    , lvl + 1 -- increase level by 1
    from @Family F
    join cte1 P on P.ParentID = F.ID -- this is the recursion
) 

,cte3 AS(
    select ID as cte3ID,STUFF(( -- stuff removes the first ','
        SELECT ',' + ctePerson
        FROM cte1
        WHERE cteID = F.ID
        ORDER by lvl DESC -- order by level DESC to start with latest ancestor
        FOR XML PATH ('')

        ), 1, 1, '') as People
    from @Family F
    where ID=@ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE3
```

Comment: Man, that is so nice.